# Allow only specific MAC addresses in Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, permissions, mac-address

Is it possible with `.htaccess` files to only allow requests from a specific MAC address instead of an IP address?

And if the answer is `yes`, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: No

Ethernet MAC is not transferred in a IP packet, only in the Ethernet header. When the IP packet leaves the LAN (technically the local broadcast domain) the Ethernet header is stripped off and the MAC address is "lost".